# python-Interpolate polynomial where coefficients are matrices

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a polynomial of the form:

```
p(y) = A + By + Cy^2 ... + Dy^n
```

Here, each of the coefficients `A,B,..,D` are matrices (and therefore `p(y)` is also a matrix). Say I interpolate the polynomial at `n+1` points. I should now be able to solve this system. I'm trying to do this in Numpy. I have the following code right now:

```
a = np.vander([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2]) #polynomial degree is 12, a -> (12x12)
b = np.random.rand(12,60,60) #p(x) is a 60x60 matrix that I have evaluated at 12 points
x = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: solve: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (m,m),(m,n)->(m,n) (size 60 is different from 12)
```

How can I solve this system in Numpy to get `x`? Is there a general mathematical trick to this?

Comment: Your dimensions don't match. As in the error: `(m,m),(m,n)->(m,n)`. Your `a` is 12x12 and `b` is 60x60. At a guess your `a` needs to be 12x60 or `b` needs to be 12x60

Comment: Actually @ashgetstazered, he seems to be trying to do `(m,m),(m,n,n),->(m,n,n)`, but `np.linalg.solve` is ony valid for scalar polynomials.  Even with higher dimension parameters you're just doing the scalar regression in parallel.  Multi-dimensional regression is one of the "hard" tasks of machine learning, so I doubt there's going to be an easy answer here, but if there is I'd be interestd in seeing it too.

Comment: Oh wait, duh.  `y` isn't a matrix, it's a scalar.  You can just do it as scalar regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you're just doing 3600 12d polynomial regressions and composing the coefficients into matrices.  For instance, the component `p(y)[0,0]` is just:

```
p(y)[0, 0] = A[0, 0] + B[0, 0] * y + C[0, 0] * y**2 ... + D[0, 0] * y**n
```

The problem is that `np.linalg.solve` can only take one dimension of coefficients. But since your matrix elements are all independent (`y` is scalar), you can `ravel` them and you can do the calulation with the form `(m,m),(m,n**2) -> (m,n**2)` and reshape back to a matrix.  So try:

```
a = np.vander([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2]) #polynomial degree is 12, a -> (12x12)
b = np.random.rand(12,60,60) #p(x) is a 60x60 matrix that I have evaluated at 12 points
s = b.shape
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b.reshape(s[0], -1))
x = x.reshape(s)
```